# Instagram redirect-uri fails for localhost

Tags: php, localhost, oauth-2.0, instagram

I am writing a PHP app to fetch all my photos with Instagram using their API. However, what puzzles me is, I run the app on my hosted server it works perfectly fine and the same app running locally does not work.

Here are some points on the app workflow:

1. The user sees the homepage and he will be prompted with 'sign-in with Instagram'
2. User signs in with Instagram and authorizes the app.
3. Instagram redirects the user.
4. The app then makes a request for access_token and receives it.
5. Using the access_token, the app will send further requests for user media
6. The response is parsed and the links to the images are now provided to the user.

All the above mentioned process works fine on my hosted server but fails at 'Step 3.' and redirects user to home page of my app.

The problem is localhost being the redirect_uri. Does anyone have a solution to this problem to use the app locally?

P.S: I have registered two separate clients on Instagram: one for locally hosted development and the other on a web server.

Also, I have tried localtunnel. Did not help either.

Comment: What exactly is the problem -- will instagram not allow you to use localhost in the redirect_uri? Or can you only configure one redirect_uri and you need it to work both for the deployment server and when developing locally?

Comment: @JMM, Instagram does allow localhost as redirect_uri. The issue is I am not able to redirect to localhost. No, I have two separate client registrations; one for developing locally and the other client registration for production.

Comment: "The issue is I am not able to redirect to localhost." What happens? Are you saying when the recdirect to `localhost` is received your browser ends up at another hostname instead, the one you use for your production server?

Comment: @JMM, No, the redirect_uri "does not" end up at another hostname. It is still "localhost"

Comment: So is the problem that it ends up at `http://localhost/` instead of `http://localhost/some/path`?

Comment: @JMM, Hmm.. Ends up at both `http://localhost/` and  `http://localhost/some/path/`

Comment: What exactly is your query string when you are calling the authorization endpoint from your localhost instance?

Comment: @JanGerlinger, Here it is https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=http://localhost/success.php&scope=basic&response_type=code . I am substituting my CLIENT_ID, just that I cannot post it public. ;-)

Comment: So Instagram should correctly set a redirect and `http://localhost/success.php` should be in your browser's address bar. Is this the case, or is the browser showing anything else?

Comment: @JanGerlinger, When I hit `http://localhost/success.php` on my browser it loads the content of `success.php`. The part of code that should be executed never even reaches `http://localhost/success.php` when redirected.

Comment: What do you mean by "never even reaches"? Is there some localhost URL in your address bar or some Instagram URL after logging in? Or something else?

Answer (score 8):

I know its a very very very old Question. but for those who get to this page hoping a solution:

instagram currently does not allow to use something like localhost or `myvhost.test` in redirection url, whats more it requires the url to be certified (https).

so the only working solution I could find is using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). you should download it from the url, open it and type a localhost virtual domain name along with a specific port number like `ngrok http myLocalUrl.test/app 80`, hit enter and it will gives you two temporary public links.

it will remain valid until you close the `ngrok` command line. you can direct the link to a specific port number and direct the port number to specific folder path of the application in your localhost.
the tutorials provided by `ngrok` is simple enough if you did not understand my hints.

Comment: as a comment you can use this thing for anything that requires https, so you can even use it for something like telegram bot development and so on

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this issue trying to develop an Instagram App using NodeJS/Express.

I got around this by using my computer's external local IP rather than localhost, which you can `grep` for. I assume you're on a *nix machine, so do a very simple (and crude)

```
$ ifconfig | grep inet
```

which will return you a few ip and MAC addresses, one of them being your external IP. However this is lousy because it means every time you switch IPs you'll have to update your application's redirect_url with Instagram as well as update any code that relies on it.

Thankfully, there exists services like [no-ip](https://www.no-ip.com) that will basically provide free DDNS service to you, so you need simply register a hostname with them and then drop that into your DEV env code as well as your development client's redirect url and you're set to go!